# Simple Login Application Using PHP

Tags: php, html, easyphp

I created a Login App. When I enter user name and password it always displays the PHP code in the page it doesn't run the code, it just displays it why?

Second thing is that I created database using EasyPHP but I don't know if my site has access to the database or not. I placed the site inside the EasyPHP local web file, here is my code:

**html file:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Library</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            html {
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif ;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size: 24px ;
                text-align: center ;
            }
            #wrapper {
                top: 30%
                margin: 0 auto
            }
            #form {
                margin: auto ;
                width: 200px ;
                heigh: 100px ;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = "wrapper">
            <h1>Library log in</h1>
            <form id = "form" action="login.php" method="post" >
                UserName: <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" >
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**php file:**

```php
<?php 
    session_start();

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password']; 

    if ($username&&$password){

            $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); or die ("Couldn't connect") ;
            mysql_select_db("phplogin") or die ("Couldn't find db") ;
    }
    else {
        echo "invalid username or password";

    }

?>
```

The database name is `phplogin`

I am opening the file from my hard drive not from a web host.

The error is when I run the site, then fill the form and press the login button it displays the PHP code. It should send me to an empty page or display an error message if the data was wrong.

I already changed to `session_start();` same error.

Comment: Is your file extension `.php` or `.html`/`.html`?

Comment: Also, are you opening the file from your local hard drive or is it hosted somewhere?

Comment: change your `session_start` to `session_start();`

Comment: @LoremIpsum the OP has no errors because as they stated: *...the page it doesn't run the code it just display it*

Comment: I think we are talking to ourselves....the OP has left the building I think.

Comment: http://codingcyber.com/simple-login-script-php-and-mysql-64/#

Comment: i answered all you questions in my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<?php 
    session_start();

     $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); or die ("Couldn't connect") ;
     mysql_select_db("phplogin") or die ("Couldn't find db") ;

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password']; 

    if ($username&&$password){

        //create a file success.php
        header("location:success.php");

    }
    else {
        echo "invalid username or password";

    }

?>
```

Comment: if we know when that kind of problem happen we can solve the problem

Comment: Where is your database located?

Comment: Where is your php file located?

Comment: The are not running a server, that is why it's not working.

Comment: when i took a code from the internet testing if it will work or not the same problem happened so it may be the database accessibility problem  or localhost problem, do i need to download something to run a php code or not.

Comment: it should be in a server ?

Comment: wait i am going to test something

Comment: i should of used easyphp to run the code not run it using the browser like normal html

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the extension is `.php` not `.html`
Next your `session_start` is wrong make it `session_start()`
Then make sure you are running in your local_host you can try xammp

Answer (score 0):

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Refer this link to config ur apache and php for mac

Comment: explain more please .

Comment: I guess u need to configure ur Apache2 so that it will understand which makes the Php file to run. by default.